# XSLT - Remove output parent element if no child element was mapped

Tags: xslt-1.0

Imagine the following schema as input

```xml
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="In">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="InA">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="InA1" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="InA2" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="InA3" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="InB">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="InB1" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="InB2" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And example would be

```xml
<In>
  <InA>
    <InA1>InA1_0</InA1>
    <InA2>InA2_0</InA2>
    <InA3>InA3_0</InA3>
  </InA>
  <InB>
    <InB1>InB1_0</InB1>
    <InB2>InB2_0</InB2>
  </InB>
</In>
```

Now, i need to map this to another schema, as some of the rules are:

- Out/Out1 mapped from In/InA/InA1 if value != ''
- Out/Out2 mapped from In/InB/InB2 if value != ''
- Out/Out3 mapped from In/InA/InA3 if value != ''
- Out should only be present if at least one of the childs was mapped

The only way I figured to do this would be to do an if before Out element, but this is very tedious and problematic the more childs Out has.

```xml
<xsl:if test="/In/InA/InA1 != '' and /In/InA/InB2 != '' and /In/InA/InA3 != ''">
<Out>
  <xsl:if test="/In/InA/InA1 != ''">
  <Out1>
  <xsl:value-of select="/In/InA/InA1/text()">
  </Out1>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="/In/InA/InB2 != ''">
  <Out2>
  <xsl:value-of select="/In/InB/InB2/text()">
  </Out2>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="/In/InA/InA3 != ''">
  <Out3>
  <xsl:value-of select="/In/InA/InA3/text()">
  </Out3>
  </xsl:if>
</Out>
</xsl:if>
```

Anyone has any other way of doing this in a single map?

Answer (score 0):

here is what I came out with. The idea is to do the inner map in a variable and then check if the variable is empty. If it is not, then i can map.

```
<xsl:variable name="out-Node">
  <xsl:if test="/In/InA/InA1 != ''">
    <Out1>
      <xsl:value-of select="/In/InA/InA1/text()">
    </Out1>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="/In/InA/InB2 != ''">
    <Out2>
      <xsl:value-of select="/In/InB/InB2/text()">
    </Out2>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="/In/InA/InA3 != ''">
    <Out3>
      <xsl:value-of select="/In/InA/InA3/text()">
    </Out3>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="$out-Node != ''">
  <Out>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$out-Node"/>
  </Out>
</xsl:if>
```

Of course, this approach must have it issues, I guess one of them would be performance.